# How do I rewrite SQL statement with OR clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have checked other questions regarding this, but could not resolve issue

```
$this->db->where(array('sender_deletedS' => 1, 'receiver_deleted' => 0 ));
            $this->db->or_where(array('sender_deletedS' => 0, 'receiver_deleted' => 1 ));
            $this->db->or_where(array('sender_deletedS' => 0, 'receiver_deleted' => 0 ));
            $query2 = $this->db->get('message');
```

It produces

```
SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `sender_deletedS` = 1 AND `receiver_deleted` =0 OR `sender_deletedS` =0 OR `receiver_deleted` = 1 OR `sender_deletedS` =0 OR `receiver_deleted` =0
```

but I want this

```
SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `sender_deletedS` = 1 AND `receiver_deleted` =0 OR `sender_deletedS` =0 AND `receiver_deleted` = 1 OR `sender_deletedS` =0 AND `receiver_deleted` =0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "sender_deleted = 1 AND receiver_deleted = 0 OR   sender_deleted = 0 AND receiver_deleted = 1 OR 
sender_deleted = 0 AND receiver_deleted = 0
"; 

$this->db->where($sql);

$this->db->get('message') ;
```

The statement can be stored and executed using the variable as shown in the example above

Answer (score 1):

If you are so confusing using Query Builder or Active Record, try traditional SQL method. It's easy to understand also

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `sender_deletedS` = 1 AND `receiver_deleted` =0 OR `sender_deletedS` =0 AND `receiver_deleted` = 1 OR `sender_deletedS` =0 AND `receiver_deleted` =0");
```

---

> > `or_where` will produce one `OR` joined statement. If its combined its act as `AND`.

**Example 01**

```
$this->db->or_where('user_id =', 0);
$this->db->or_where('member_id =',  1);
```

Output will be

```
WHERE user_id = 0 OR member_id = 1
```

**Example 02**

```
$this->db->or_where(array('user_id' => 0, 'member_id' => 1 ));
```

Output will be

```
WHERE user_id = 0 AND member_id = 1
```

**Example 03**

```
$this->db->or_where(array('user_id' => 0, 'member_id' => 1 ));
$this->db->or_where('library_id =',  0);
```

Output will be

```
WHERE user_id = 0 AND member_id = 1 OR library_id = 0
```

[`$this->db->or_where()` in codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)